# Masters in Computers Science OR Game Design and Development?

Tags: game-design, software-engineering, game-industry, education

Hey guys so I've been very confused on what path to take in terms of education. I'm a soon to be computer science graduate with a BS in Computer Programming. 
My hope is to one day land a job in the gaming industry but I've read a few posts on what people have said against and for a degree in game design. They have all been about a bachelors degree and in my case that will already be obtained.

It is true that a computer science degree is more general and that many non gaming employers will not think of it as any less, compared to a game design degree. But since I already will receive a computer science degree will it still look bad if I have a masters in game design and a BS in computer science when interviewed for a gaming company and non gaming company? As well as is the masters in game design worth it or should I stick to with computer science?

what i hope to gain from my degree is further understanding of game creation, I want to develop my own game and I have been learning to use Unity and Unreal but want to expand my knowledge in other areas.

I want your input on what you consider the best choice and why.

Thanks.

Comment: Masters degrees are not needed to find a job. With a CS degree, you can find a job as a game dev, and as a non-game dev. IMHO, a CS degree is better than a game specific degree. And IMHO, don't waste your time and your money with a master degree. Practice makes perfect. Find a job in game dev, and you'll learn _a lot_.